# Difference in conditional rendering (React)

Tags: reactjs

I know I can conditionally render my React component in two ways:

```
const SomeComponent = ({isReady}) => {
  if (!isReady) {
    return null;
  }
  return (
    <div>
      ..rest of component elements
    </div>
  ) 
}
```

Or I could do it in a place this component is used:

```
const MainComponent = () => {
   ...props from redux or some state etc.

   return (
     <div>
       ..rest of component elements

        {!isReady && <SomeComponent />

     </div>
   ) 
}
```

Is it the same about performance? Is it just opinionated or one of the ways is better?

Comment: Both seem fine, but the second way is preferable as there is no extra prop chaining and you can code the logic in a cleaner one line method

Comment: But I guess it is cleaner in my example. When MainComponent consists of many child components and there are some conditions readability becomes much worse...

Answer (score 0):

Difference is that which part is conditional.

**about performance :** 2nd scenario is good but it depends of which features you need, some time you want to re-calculate/re-render whole component then 1st scenario is useful, some time you just want to render only part of your component or only some component then 2nd scenario is good.

1. First scenario

---

You put condition for your main function so what is inside your return will re-mounted and re-rendered, also child components. with that all child component will go through `lifecycle hooks (useEffect)` if you have them.

**Notice here :** your `div` and `..rest of component elements` will re-mounted and child component will go through `lifecycle hooks (useEffect)` if you have them.

2. Second scenario

---

You put condition inside JSX so only `SomeComponent` and which are `with condition` will be re-mounted and re-rendered and will go through `lifecycle hooks (useEffect)` if you have them.

**Notice here :** your upper `div` and `..rest of component elements` will not change as its not affected by this.

if any doubt please comment.

Answer (score 0):

Beware if `isReady` ( or any other variable ) is `0`, it would render 0 on the screen.

Example:-

```
export default function App() {
  const [money, setMoney] = React.useState(null);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const id = setTimeout(() => setMoney(0), 2000);
    return () => clearTimeout(id);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {money && <p>Money is {money}</p>}
      {money ? <p>Money is {money}</p> : null}
    </div>
  );
}
```

You could check the example here => https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-k8qwhj

---

> General rule of thumb, use ternary or `if-else` if value is of type `number` otherwise use `&&`